# How to search for a string on the internet although it was already found when using Albert?

Tags: launcher, albert

- OS: Arch Linux (6.2.6.arch1-1)
- Albert: 0.20.8-1

Say I enter a phrase such as "asdfABC" in Albert and there is a result, meaning the result gets highlighted, e.g. it is a file `asdfABC.odt`. But I would rather like to search for that string on Google or DuckDuckGo or ... wherever through Albert.

Is it possible  to search for a string on the internet although it was already found when using Albert?

Comment: Doesn't it do Google search if you use the trigger, i.e. typing in the search box `gg asdfABC`?

Comment: @Peregrino69 Sure, it does.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. I didn't know about Albert before - thanks a lot for the new tool :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 Well, thank you for the effort. However that is not what I asked and more like a reply to a whataboutism. That much I already knew myself... that it is possible to use bangs, shortcuts, triggers and whatever custom method one can come up with. I am looking for the issue when one is "caught in that corner"-problem.

Comment: That's OK, no need to accept it :-) In that case you should edit the question and clarify your exact need and use case.

Comment: Use case clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a big thank you to the dev: Holding down the super/meta/windows key shows the options for web search. :)

Answer (score 0):

To search from the internet invoke the search using a trigger. For example to perform Google search `gg asdfABC`. The default triggers in Albert are:

```
gg  ->  Google
yt  ->  Youtube
ama ->  Amazon
eb  ->  Ebay
gh  ->  GitHub
=   ->  Wolfram Alpha
dd  ->  DuckDuckGo
```

Triggers can be modified and new ones added via the Settings / WebSearch.